# getting a value error when trying to compare lists in python

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to compare two elements of a 2d list in python, and this error popped up:
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

it refers to this line:

```py
while p[0] == p[1]: p = randint(0, self.size, size=(2, 2))
```

But I'm not sure where exactly I'm trying to get the truth value of anything...

How can I solve this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You are making a 2x2 array, are you trying to compare rows, columns, or something else?

Comment: "I'm not sure where exactly I'm trying to get the truth value of anything..." - How about `p[0] == p[1]`?

Comment: share the entire code snippet for  more clarity

Answer (score 1):

Numpy is not Python!

After `p = randint(0, self.size, size=(2, 2))`, `p` is a 2D numpy array.

Equality between numpy arrays does not produce a boolean like what is expected for all Python types, but a numpy array of booleans of same dimensions of the compared arrays. In numpy wording, the equality is *broadcasted* over the array.

Here you probably want: `(p[0] == p[1]).all()`. It will be a boolean that is true iif all element of both arrays match.

This numpy feature does make sense because it allows very efficent operations, but is enough to break `in` semantics for any Python container that would contain numpy arrays.